# Xpath - How to get every nth node

Tags: xml, xpath

In below xml response I want to select every 200th element. I can't figure out how to get it to work.

**URL**

```
http://localhost:5000/sample?path=//*[@name="temperature"]&count=10
```

**XML RESPONSE**

```
<Temperature dataItemId="temperature" timestamp="2022-10-03T13:00:13.2062+02:00" name="temperature" sequence="46820421">20</Temperature>
<Temperature dataItemId="temperature" timestamp="2022-10-03T13:00:14.2968+02:00" name="temperature" sequence="46820470">20.1</Temperature>
<Temperature dataItemId="temperature" timestamp="2022-10-03T13:00:15.3875+02:00" name="temperature" sequence="46820512">20</Temperature>
<Temperature dataItemId="temperature" timestamp="2022-10-03T13:00:16.4781+02:00" name="temperature" sequence="46820554">20.2</Temperature>
<Temperature dataItemId="temperature" timestamp="2022-10-03T13:00:16.5687+02:00" name="temperature" sequence="46820596">20</Temperature>
<Temperature dataItemId="temperature" timestamp="2022-10-03T13:00:17.6593+02:00" name="temperature" sequence="46820638">19.9</Temperature>
<Temperature dataItemId="temperature" timestamp="2022-10-03T13:00:18.0006+02:00" name="temperature" sequence="46820696">20</Temperature>
<Temperature dataItemId="temperature" timestamp="2022-10-03T13:00:19.8406+02:00" name="temperature" sequence="46820738">20</Temperature>
<Temperature dataItemId="temperature" timestamp="2022-10-03T13:00:20.9312+02:00" name="temperature" sequence="46820780">20</Temperature>
<Temperature dataItemId="temperature" timestamp="2022-10-03T13:00:21.0218+02:00" name="temperature" sequence="46820822">20</Temperature>
```

Comment: What is the software you have running on `http://localhost:5000/`?

Comment: IIS 10 with PHP 7.4

Comment: No, I mean what's the application software? What is the PHP code? What's responsible for responding to that `sample` URL and interpreting the `path` parameter as an XPath expression to be evaluated against some corpus of XML data?

Comment: The machine runs an MTconnect agent that spits out machine monitoring data https://www.mtconnect.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [mod function](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#numbers) like this:

```
http://localhost:5000/sample?path=//*[@name="temperature"][position() mod 200 = 0]
```

As Conal Tuohy suggests you probably have de url-encode the XPath like this:

```
http://localhost:5000/sample?path=%2F%2F%2A%5B%40name%3D%22temperature%22%5D%5Bposition%28%29%20mod%20200%20%3D%200%5D
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I try your solution I get the following error: "The path could not be parsed. Invalid syntax"

Comment: in what program language do you get the error. In my xml-editor it works perfectly

Comment: that would be xml. <Error errorCode="INVALID_XPATH">

Comment: Misunderstanding: xml is not a program language

Comment: The XPath which @SiebeJongebloed suggests is a valid XPath, so the problem is elsewhere. Perhaps you need to ensure that the XPath is properly URL-encoded in your query URI? e.g. `http://localhost:5000/sample?path=%2F%2F%2A%5B%40name%3D%22temperature%22%5D%5Bposition%28%29%20mod%20200%20%3D%200%5D`